# Regex to search multiple strings spam

Tags: regex

I have a problem we are receiving many spam emails with the following strings:
`(vi@gra, v1agra, v1@gra, v!@gr@)`
I already create several regular expressions for each of the words but I don't know how to join my regular expressions to just one

```
^v[0-9]+agra$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
v[i1!][a@]gr[a@]
```

### Demo

Note that this pattern also matches `viagra`, in addition to the four viagra variants which you gave in your question.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen, I really appreciate your support. I made the validations in my code and it works wonderfully. thank you very much a big hug from guatemala